# Grep -v doesn't work when piping with locate

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, grep

I have the following command:

```
locate -br '^test.sh$'
```

The output is:

```
/home/cas/scripts/test.sh
```

I want to have the path without the name of the file. So I did the following to remove test.sh from the output:

```
locate -br '^test.sh$' | grep -v test.sh
```

I expected the output to be:

```
/home/cas/scripts/
```

But instead I just don't get an output. When I press enter, I get no output and it just waits for the next command.
See picture below

[image]

Nothing gives an output. I even tried to invert-grep something different, 'cas', but it wouldn't give any output to.
It looks like `grep -v` just doesn't work. But normal grep (so not inverted) DOES work.
Why doesn't it work? Or is there a better way to find the path to a file from anywhere, but without the file name in the output (the goal is to get `/home/cas/scripts/`)?

Comment: `.` is a meta-character equal to any char it may give false-positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `grep -v PATTERN` returns all the lines that do not contain `PATTERN`, that's why it is giving you an empty output.

The following may work for you:

```
locate -br '^test.sh$' | xargs dirname
```

Comment: "Actually grep -v PATTERN returns all the lines that do not contain PATTERN". That was the idea. PATTERN is test.sh, so that it would return everything that's not test.sh AKA /home/cas/scripts/. But the command that you gave works perfectly so thanks.

Comment: The point is that if one line contains PATTERN, then such line is not shown. It does not simply remove PATTERN from the line and then shows the result (I hope is it clear now).

Comment: @cas if you are determined to use `grep`, you could do `locate -br '^test.sh$' | grep -o '.*/'` (greedily match everything up to the last `/` and output only the matching portion) I think

Comment: @steeldriver yes, sure. Since OP used the locate utility, my solution uses that one.

Comment: @dariofac apologies, my comment should have been directed at the OP

Comment: you should probably use null termination `-0` or dirname will break on whitespace.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @dariofac 's command worked perfectly. And I understand now that grep -v removes the complete line that matches, instead of (what i thought) only the pattern. steeldrivers's that command works to. I'm not determined to use grep. I don't care what I use, as long as I get the result that I want and I get that with your and dariofac's command.